# Run tests after EAR builds

Tags: java, maven, testing, jboss-arquillian

I have multi module project. It builds to EAR. I added to it arquillian library. Every submodule has got own tests but to work it has to have other modules compiles. I would like to run all tests after ear builds and then use this ear to deploy and test. Is there any possibility to do this in single maven build lifecycle?

Answer (score 1):

Tests that you want to run after ear is built should be implemented in the same project (module) that builds `ear`.

Tests that are executed when ear is deployed in container are called "integration tests" and are executed at phase `integration-test`. You can call such test cases using special pattern (e.g. `BlaBlaIntegrationTest`) and perform appropriate configuration in `pom.xml` to run only these tests on "integration tests" phase and ignore them when you are running regular unit tests.

Comment: Alex is right. I have a preference for putting integration tests (with Arquillian or other tools) into a seperate project/module because it makes it straight forward to set them up in a continuous delivery pipeline in a CI server (mostly Jenkins) as separate step.

Comment: I would definitely consider creating a separate integration test module a best practice for business apps.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Lifecycle Phases are:

```
validate - validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available
compile - compile the source code of the project
test - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit testing framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged or deployed
package - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.
integration-test - process and deploy the package if necessary into an environment where integration tests can be run
verify - run any checks to verify the package is valid and meets quality criteria
install - install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally
deploy - done in an integration or release environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.
```

I would suggest, that you pack your arquillian tests in the integration-test phase.
Arquillian, should deploy the micro-deployments on it's own on the testsmachine, if it is configured in the right way.